# summarize groups into intervals using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

H,
I have a data frame like this:

```
d <- data.frame(v1=seq(0,9.9,0.1),
            v2=rnorm(100),
            v3=rnorm(100))

> head(d)
   v1          v2         v3
1 0.0 -0.01431916 -0.5005415
2 0.1 -1.01575590  1.5307473
3 0.2  1.00081065 -0.1730830
4 0.3 -1.20697918  0.5105118
5 0.4 -2.16698578 -1.0120544
6 0.5  0.33886508  0.4797016
```

I now want a new data frame that summarizes all values in the intervals 0-0.99, 1-1.99, 2-2.99, 3-3.99,.... by the mean for example

like this

```
start end mean.v2 mean.v3
    0   1     0.2     0.1
    1   2     0.5     0.4
```

and so on

thanks

*Update* I should add that in my real data set the observations in each interval are of different lengths and they don't always start at zero or end at 10

Comment: You can use `cut`.  Perhaps `d %>% group_by(v1 = cut(v1, breaks= c(-Inf,0, 0.99, 1.99, 2.99, Inf))) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean))`

Comment: @akrun I added some further information to the question. There should be a way where I don't have to set the intervals manually

Answer (score 13, accepted):

here is one way using `cut()` as suggested by @akrun:

```
d %>% mutate( ints = cut(v1 ,breaks = 11)) %>% 
   group_by(ints) %>% 
   summarise( mean.v2 = mean(v2) , mean.v3 = mean(v3) )
```

Comment: thanks, but I added some additional constraints that I forgot. The observations in each intervals may be different and it should work in different data sets with different start and end values

Comment: my solution is agnostic about the number of observations in each interval and their range, you just set the number of breaks you require. Maybe I misunderstand you; in that case you should please provide a minimal exmaple and expected output.

Comment: so breaks is something like max(ceiling(d$v1))+1  ? Is there a way to get the interval inclusion brackets from (..] to [..) ?

Comment: from the help of `cut`: "When breaks is specified as a single number, the range of the data is divided into breaks pieces of equal length, and then the outer limits are moved away by 0.1% of the range [...]"

Comment: To "get the interval inclusion brackets from (..] to [..)"  the help of `cut()` tells you that it has an argument  `right`.

Answer (score 5):

Based on @David H"s answer, with 2 options to choose from:

1. Generate intervals with `cut()` using a vector of breaks
2. Generate intervals with `floor()` instead of `cut()`

Create data

```
set.seed(33)
d <- data.frame(v1=seq(0,9.9,0.1),
            v2=rnorm(100),
            v3=rnorm(100))
```

## Generate intervals with `cut()` using a vector of breaks

For that simple example you could use `breaks <- 0:10` but to be more general let's take the min and max of `d$v1`.

```
breaks <- floor(min(d$v1)):ceiling(max(d$v1))
breaks 
# [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Summarise over intervals 0-0.99, 1-1.99, 2-2.99, 3-3.99,....

```
d %>% 
    mutate(interval = cut(v1,
                          breaks, 
                          include.lowest = TRUE, 
                          right = FALSE)) %>%
    group_by(interval) %>% 
    summarise( mean.v2 = mean(v2) , mean.v3 = mean(v3))

# Source: local data frame [10 x 3]
# 
#    interval     mean.v2     mean.v3
#      (fctr)       (dbl)       (dbl)
# 1     [0,1) -0.13040624 -0.20781247
# 2     [1,2)  0.26505794  0.51990167
# 3     [2,3)  0.13451628  1.12066174
# 4     [3,4)  0.23451272 -0.14773437
# 5     [4,5)  0.34326922  0.28567969
# 6     [5,6) -0.77059944 -0.16629580
# 7     [6,7) -0.17617190  0.03320797
# 8     [7,8)  0.86550135 -0.24664350
# 9     [8,9) -0.06652047 -0.27798769
# 10   [9,10] -0.10424865  0.24060163
```

## Generate intervals with `floor()` instead of `cut()`

Cheat a little bit by subtracting a tiny number `1e-9` from the end of each interval.

```
d %>% 
    mutate(start = floor(v1), end = start + 1 - 1e-9 ) %>%
    group_by(start, end) %>% 
    summarise_each(funs(mean))

# Source: local data frame [10 x 4]
# Groups: start [?]
# 
#    start   end     mean.v2     mean.v3
#    (dbl) (dbl)       (dbl)       (dbl)
# 1      0     1 -0.13040624 -0.20781247
# 2      1     2  0.26505794  0.51990167
# 3      2     3  0.13451628  1.12066174
# 4      3     4  0.23451272 -0.14773437
# 5      4     5  0.34326922  0.28567969
# 6      5     6 -0.77059944 -0.16629580
# 7      6     7 -0.17617190  0.03320797
# 8      7     8  0.86550135 -0.24664350
# 9      8     9 -0.06652047 -0.27798769
# 10     9    10 -0.10424865  0.24060163
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the floor() and ceiling() functions. And the ifelse() in cases where the interval is 1 - 1 or 2 - 2 for example.

```
d<-data.frame(v1=seq(0,9.9,0.1),
              v2=rnorm(100),
              v3=rnorm(100))          

library(dplyr)

d%>%
        mutate(start=floor(v1),
               end=ifelse(ceiling(v1)==start,start+1,ceiling(v1)))%>%
        group_by(start,end)%>%
        summarise(mean.v2=mean(v2),
                  mean.v3=mean(v3))

Source: local data frame [10 x 4]
Groups: start [?]

   start   end      mean.v2     mean.v3
   (dbl) (dbl)        (dbl)       (dbl)
1      0     1  0.135180183 -0.36083298
2      1     2 -0.245567899  0.26827020
3      2     3 -0.051136441  0.14211666
4      3     4  0.252451303  0.38530797
5      4     5  0.007209073  0.30137345
6      5     6 -0.307008690  0.07662942
7      6     7  0.103271270  0.14734865
8      7     8  0.016753997 -0.02559756
9      8     9 -0.199958098 -0.21821830
10     9    10  0.532339512 -0.46509108
```

The same but including a column named intervals instead of two (start and end):

```
d%>%
        mutate(start=floor(v1),
               end=ifelse(ceiling(v1)==start,start+1,ceiling(v1)),
               interval=paste(start,"-",end))%>%
        select(-start,-end)%>%
        group_by(interval)%>%
        summarise(mean.v2=mean(v2),
                  mean.v3=mean(v3))

Source: local data frame [10 x 3]

   interval      mean.v2     mean.v3
      (chr)        (dbl)       (dbl)
1     0 - 1  0.135180183 -0.36083298
2     1 - 2 -0.245567899  0.26827020
3     2 - 3 -0.051136441  0.14211666
4     3 - 4  0.252451303  0.38530797
5     4 - 5  0.007209073  0.30137345
6     5 - 6 -0.307008690  0.07662942
7     6 - 7  0.103271270  0.14734865
8     7 - 8  0.016753997 -0.02559756
9     8 - 9 -0.199958098 -0.21821830
10   9 - 10  0.532339512 -0.46509108
```

Comment: The OP wanted the first interval to be 0-0.99. This code excludes 1 from the first interval because `floor(1) == ceiling(1)`. This is nice but less transparent than using the `cut()` function with its `right` argument.

Comment: You're right, that's why I use the ifelse() function. When you got 1 - 1, the code interpreted as 2 - 1. But you can also change the code so it can be 0 - 1 (in the ifelse function). The code is very versatile.